# Python Upload to YouTube OAuth2 problems

Tags: python, youtube, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm new to OAuth and API's but have been trying to figure out the upload_video.py script that is provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) to upload videos to my channel via Python.

My problem is I can't figure the OAuth, so I'm calling the script with the necessary arguments, but then getting re-directed to an authentication page in my browser.
This script needs to be run completely invisibly from command line and so, that doesn't work for me.

Can anybody point me in the right direction for not having to authenticate the script manually each time it's running?

I was hoping there would be an option for this in the Google dev console, to allow this kind of thing, but it doesn't appear so.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will have to at some point use a browser to complete the OAuth2 flow - it's unavoidable. The script google provides on that page does store the token in a local file, so that your program won't need to go through the process again every time it runs, as long as the token is still valid. You can also get your program to ask for a new token when the one it has expires, though I'm not sure if that script actually does that or not.

See: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices for information about the OAuth2 flow on devices that aren't capable of launching a browser themselves.